# Pull request for a change to a previous revision on Github

Tags: git, github

One of the dependencies my react app is using, is not functioning in iOS.
I forked the github repo of that dependency, reset to the revision of the version I am using, and made a fix to get it working in iOS.
Now I would like to contribute the fix upstream, since it still looks to be an issue with the latest code.

My issue is, we are using an old version/revision of the npm package.  The source code has since been updated to support a newer version of react that my project isn't using, so I made the change on the revision that correpsonds to the version of react we are using.

Should I make the change on the HEAD of the github repository and make a pull request, and then leave my fork hanging around so my project can pull in the dependency, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is up to the developer of that dependency, basically. But as you seem not to be able to test your change against the current version of that library, if I were the developer, I'd ask you to make a branch off of that old commit, push your change on top of it, then make a pull request and document clearly what you did.

If you want to make it a little bit easier for the developer, then try if your change can easily be rebased against the current `master`:

```
git checkout yourbranch
git rebase master
# but don't push this, throw it away
```

If that works, then the developer of that dependency should easily be able to figure out what to do.

Comment: So if the upstream project had created a branch for each version, then I would need to submit the change on that branch? And since they haven't I need to test it on the their latest code and then submit the change to that?

Comment: That would seem sensible to me.